# freed object - losing value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have the following code:

```
NSString *Items[91];
```

in the .m file above all the methods to serve as global array which in my init method i do:

```
for (j1 = 0; j1 <= 90; j1++)
    {
        Items[j1] = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
    }
```

and at some point a different method AA is triggered and do:

```
Items[40] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"40. Pers:%g each", PersExemptions];
 Items[41] =@"blah blah";
```

... etc

and at some point a different method BB is triggered and i see that for Items[40] it says  freed object, it's losing the value it had which defeat the purpose. Grr.

I would like Items  array to  keep their modified values thru the app until the end and I assumed that using the initWithFormat that i used in the init method should take care of it.
I understand that Items is c-style array (and to convert to NSMutable array would pain) if that's the problem to begin with.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: The code you have shown is not sufficient to demonstrate the problem (that is, there is nothing wrong with what you have shown). The problem likely lies elsewhere, in some code which is trashing the `Items[40]` value.

Comment: You might look again, @GregHewgill, the problem is definitely here.

Comment: I might have missed something. Please show me that I'm wrong!

Comment: I think you're assuming global == singleton. "thru the app until the end". That's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: As @dasblinkenlight points out, I'm assuming here you are not using ARC.

You're using a C-style array here, an array of NSString*.

The problem is that when you do this...

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"40. Pers:%g each", PersExemptions]`

`stringWithFormat:` returns an NSString that you do not own. If you want to hold onto that NSString in your array, you need to retain it. Or you can use the alloc/initWithString that you did earlier:

`Items[40] = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"40. Pers:%g each", PersExemptions];`

That gives you an NSString that you **do** own. But of course, that leads to another bug, which is that you just leaked whatever NSString happened to be in Items[40] a moment ago.

So you could make sure to always release the previous string each time, or you can save yourself a lot of effort and just use an NSMutableArray instead. NSMutableArray will take care of retaining each new value and releasing the one that was just replaced. I know you say that's too much effort, and without looking at your code no one else can say, but accounting for each object you store might actually be **more** effort.

I hope that helps.

Comment: @Firoze Lafeer Thank you for your explanation it helped to understand the inner working that i took for granted here. I'm planning to convert the C-Style array to NSMutableArray. As for ARC, i'm not sure how to enable it at the moment or the benefits so I'll do some due deligence on that.

Answer (score 0):

Now nsstring is:

```
NSString ** strArr;
int rows = 91;
```

Then, you'll need to use malloc, to dynamically allocate memory:

```
int i;
strArr = malloc( rows * sizeof( strArr * ) );

for( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
 strArr[ i ] = calloc( columns, sizeof( NSString ) );
}
```

Don't forget to free in your dealloc method:

```
int i;

for( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
  free( strArr[ i ] );
}
free( strArr);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i think I'll use NSMutablearrays as it seems to integrate a bit better with objectice-c.